# Bulk Message Insert to RabbitMq using C#

Tags: rabbitmq

I want to insert(publish) bulk message at once and receive 10 by 10.
Ex:- Inserting 100 messages at once (not one by one) and receive (consume) 10 by 10
I'm using C# (can answer in any programming language).

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you want to publish the messages one by one? For RabbitMQ and any consumer it does not matter. And what do you mean by receiving 10 by 10? Do you want to ACK all 10 messages after they all have been processed? What is the use case you try to implement?

Comment: Assuming you can modify the subscriber and publisher sides at your will - I would consider aggregating/caching messages in the subscriber until I have a total of 10 and only then firing a notification to the consuming component and instantly making all 10 messages available to it. Similarly, the publisher can aggregate messages in chunks of 10 and once a chunk is ready send all messages one by one.
I am unaware of such an option in the Rabbit broker itself, but I am not incredibly experienced with RabbitMQ and might be unaware of certain features.

Comment: Cross-posted here: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/rabbitmq-users/4RGn4cN3Bu8/discussion